# In adventure time, is there an episode that establishes that a wizard can see death?

Tags: episode-identification, adventure-time

It's a somewhat common trope in fantasy that wizards can see Death (as in the anthropomorphic representation of death) outside of his domain.

I can't find the episode that establishes this.

I know when Betty is taking The Ice king to Bella Noche, Death appears to Him and taunts him. I don't think this counts as he had

> Lost his powers

So is there an earlier episode in remembering that watermarked this? '[Wizard Eyes](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Wizard_Eyes)' doesn't count unless Death specifically appears.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote?  How can I improve this question?

Comment: Is this really a common trope? What well-known works feature it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is such an episode. Consider that in order to be proven, it has to be explicitly (and credibly) stated—which it hasn't, unless it's been in one of the shorts or the latest 3 episodes (which I haven't seen)—or it has to be demonstrated.

In order to be demonstrated, however, you would have to know Death's intentions. Must he be invisible? Could he make himself visible? Could he make himself selectively visible? In "Betty", the Ice King is near death, and it is also a very common trope that those near death can see Death. Again, taking that moment from "Betty" where Death appears, does Betty not see Death or is she just focused on saving Simon?

On top of that, Simon is weird in a lot of ways, and magic is not entirely consistent in Adventure Time.